# SQL exclude duplicated pairs of columns from a two-column select

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, distinct, rows

I don't really know how to describe my problem and I haven't found an answer.
I have two tables, rating and reviewer. I want to get for every pair of reviewers their names if they rated the same movie.
I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT re1.name, re2.name 
FROM reviewer re1, reviewer re2, rating ra1, rating ra2
WHERE re1.rid=ra1.rid AND re2.rid=ra2.rid AND ra1.mid=ra2.mid AND re1.rid!=re2.rid;
```

This is the tables structure: rating (rid, mid, stars, ratingdate), reviewer(rid, name)

This is what I want to get:

```
NAME                       NAME              
Daniel Lewis               Elizabeth Thomas 
Elizabeth Thomas           James Cameron 
Ashley White               Chris Jackson
Mike Anderson              Sarah Martinez
Brittany Harris            Chris Jackson
```

This is what I get:

```
NAME                           NAME                         
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Daniel Lewis                   Elizabeth Thomas               
Elizabeth Thomas               James Cameron                  
Chris Jackson                  Brittany Harris                
Chris Jackson                  Ashley White                   
Ashley White                   Chris Jackson                  
James Cameron                  Elizabeth Thomas               
Mike Anderson                  Sarah Martinez                 
Sarah Martinez                 Mike Anderson                  
Elizabeth Thomas               Daniel Lewis                   
Brittany Harris                Chris Jackson
```

How do I remove the duplicate rows where the name1 and name2 have already been selected as name2, name1 ?
I hope I was clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Take some time and help us to know logic behind your query i.e. what are you trying to solve, schema involved, sample data in those schema and then output what you are expecting.

Comment: I think I already explained what I'm traing to solve, and the output I am expecting. Here is the data in my two tables involved: 
http://i57.tinypic.com/6qaz47.png

http://i62.tinypic.com/2v36cfs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very subtle change (`>` vs your `!=`), but what you want to do is use a diagonal elimination approach, whereby you exclude any reviewer with a `rid` lower than the current one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT re1.name, re2.name 
FROM reviewer re1
  INNER JOIN rating ra1
    ON re1.rid=ra1.rid
CROSS JOIN
  reviewer re2
  INNER JOIN rating ra2
    ON re2.rid=ra2.rid
WHERE ra1.mid=ra2.mid AND  re1.rid > re2.rid;
```

This way, you don't 'double count' pairs of reviewers which already have a match on the opposite / symmetric side of the diagonal.

I've also taken the liberty of moving the JOIN conditions into `JOINs`, rather than in the `WHERE` clause.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f16df/6)

Answer (score 0):

This query selects all reviewers of each movie and pairs them up with all other reviewers (whether or not they have reviewed the same movie). It then uses an `exists` to only keep reviewers that have reviewed the same movie.

```
select re1.name, re2.name
from reviewer re1 join reviewer re2 on re2.rid < re1.rid
join rating ra1 on ra1.rid = re1.rid
where exists (
    select 1 from rating ra2
    where ra2.mid = ra1.mid
    and ra2.rid = re2.rid
)
```